# How to make an item in a listview move up when it is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

How can I build a listview similar to gmail app style? To be specific, when I click an item to show more details, the item moves up, becomes the title of a new activity and last, another views shows below the title to display details. There are 2 questions:

1. How can I make the clicked item move up? (I believe it's related to animation)
2. Is it a listview + a transition animation problem or is there a view handling this kind of task?

Answer (score 0):

as i have interpreted, you want an item to go to top and open the page/view related to that. for that you can do this:-

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
startActivity(someIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use activity transition !

this library is what you want:

[PreLollipopTransition](https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition)